# How to use sed to replace a string using the line number on a remote machine using ssh?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, sed, grep

I am trying to replace a string in a file that which is on a remote machine. Firstly, I have to get the line number using grep command and then by using that line number should replace the string that which is there in that line.

My code looks like:
my script file **sc.sh**.

```
# path of script.sh on remote machine
file_path="/home/user/script.sh"

#file-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.txt using for file-1.0.5.txt

sshpass -p 'pswd' ssh user@remote-01 "bash -s" <<EOF
n=$(grep -wn "/tmp/xyz/file-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.txt\" $file_path | cut -d : -f 1)

sed -i '{$n}s/old_string/new_string/}' $file_path;
EOF
```

the commands in EOF block are working on my host machine but these commands are not working on remote machine, while using ssh. Can someone help me ? TIA.

Comment: First things first: try to `ls -l $file_path` on the remote m/c. What does it return?

Comment: Maybe see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38627863/874188

Answer (score 2):

```
file_path="/home/user/script.sh"

sshpass -p 'pswd' ssh user@remote-01 "bash -s" <<EOF
sed -i -e '\|/tmp/xyz/file-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.txt|s/old_string/new_string/' "$file_path"
EOF
```

---

### Explanation

- Assuming your `/home/user/script.sh` file is visible on the remote m/c, then there's no need to first look for line numbers where the `s///` commands need to happen. You need to realize the `sed` allows for `/regex/s///` as well to select the line numbers where the subs will be made.

Comment: file_path="/home/user/script.sh" is the file location on remote machine.